# Django admin. Custom field formatting in list_display

Tags: django-admin

I have the following class in admin.py

```
 class MaterialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('sp', 'number', 'shelf')
```

'sp' is species name, and I need to show it in italics for concordance with zoological nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

Django Admin will add a CSS class to every field on the list. So if your field is "sp", its  will have the "field-sp" class. (Take a look at the Django Admin html source to see what I'm talking about.)

So it's just a matter of adding italics on the CSS for that "field-sp" class. There are several ways to achieve this, but the simpler one would be to [override the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) for that model on the admin to make it load additional CSS.

On the templates folder, you will need to have admin/name_of_your_app/name_of_the_model/change_list.html. The contents of that file can be as follows:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block extrastyle %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/this_is_my_css_file.css" %}" />
{% endblock %}
```

(You need to extend the original change_list.html for everything else to show up. And in this example I'm loading staticfiles to load the CSS file. If you manage your assets differently, this might vary.)

The [original change_list.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html) has this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/changelists.css" %}" />
```

So modifying that CSS could help, but it's more proper to just override the template for your model. After all, there might be an 'sp' field on another model that does not need to be in italics.

(Conversely, if the species name will ALWAYS be in italic, then yes, you might just define italics on the global admin CSS and be done for all models.)

I hope my explanation was clear! YMMV according to your Django version -- I just tried it on a Django 1.7 project and worked as described.